# Web content is not getting loaded when opening on Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, microsoft-edge

Can you please suggest what changes i need to do with tags so that it could work on Microsoft Edge browser

```
xsl file 


<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:import href="common.xsl" />

<xsl:template match="@ID">
<td width="15%"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="COND-ID">
<td width="10%"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CLIENT">
<td width="15%"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SYST-NM">
<td width="15%"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DESC-TX">
<td width="15%"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SYST-CLNT-ID">
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMCLIENT">
<td width="15%"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Provision/CLNT-MPNG">

<table width="100%">
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
<tr class="headC1">
<th width="15%">Client Id</th>
<th width="15%">EmClient Id</th>
<th width="15%">System Name</th>
<th width="15%">System Key Value</th>
<th width="15%">Description</th>    
<th>System Client Id</th>   
<th width="10%">Condition id</th>   
</tr>
    
</xsl:if>

    <tr class="dataC1"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CLIENT"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EMCLIENT"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SYST-NM"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@ID"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DESC-TX"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SYST-CLNT-ID"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="COND-ID"/>
    
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Web content is not getting loaded on microsoft edge browser while it's working fine on IE.
I have made changes in XSL file but it couldn't help.
Can anyone suggest what i need to do to get it loaded and make supportive on Microsoft Edge Browser as well.

Comment: You need to be more specific: do you load the content over HTTP(S)? Or from the file system? Is that the old Microsoft Edge or the new Chromium based Edge? Loading XSLT in XML with `<?xml-stylesheet?>` over the file system is not supported in Chrome and I think that way also not in the new, Chromium based Edge. So you might need to use a local web server.

Comment: Content is not getting loaded over both HTTP(S).And its a new chromium based Edge.

Comment: Use F12 to fire up the developer console and should show error or warnings that the XSLT was not loaded I think. As I said, like with Chrome, you will need to use a local HTTP server. Or check whether there is a command line option, Chrome has one, not sure whether the Microsoft Edge clone has a similar one. You could also add a tag for the browser to see what other users have to say.

Comment: You can try to start Edge with `msedge --allow-file-access-from-files` to work around the problem.

Comment: How / Where do I set the "allow-file-access-from-files" configuration option in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: You need to run Edge from the command line

Comment: Are you trying to load xml file on Edge? Is there any error in console when you check it on Edge using F12 dev tools? Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue. We can't locate the issue with only the brief text description.

Comment: added code snippet

Comment: So what does F12 and the error console show when your XSLT is not applied?